# How to copy contents of tkinter window to presentation slides?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have written a small code with few clickable links and some shapes depicting a sample architectural diagram.I need the whole content of the output tkinter window copied into  presentation slides.How can I copy the entire contents including the clickable links?

Comment: As in, the links need to still be clickable in the presentation? I expect that would depend heavily on what software you're displaying your slides with. Powerpoint? Something else? But in any case, I'm not optimistic that it's got built-in import-from-tkinter capability.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier just to compile the program and present it as is?

Comment: I got some 50+ slides to be prepared, my code is able to prepare the the window but I have no idea how can I transfer it another doc(presentation file, numbers etc etc)